# Unable to extend my efi partition with unallocated space

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, gpt, efi

This is how the partition layout looks in the Easeus partition manager:

[image: Easeus partition manager]
Could anyone suggest how to extend my EFI partition with the unallocated space? Or some other way.. i'm having some issues due to EFI partition being too small..
Sorry for nonenglish language, 413,38 MB is the unallocated space.

Comment: You will need a good 3rd party partition software that makes a boot disk, then boot from it and merge any partitions you wish offline.

Comment: You have any software recommendations?

Comment: @MegaKoks - Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.

Answer (score -2):

This seems overcomplicated and not worth the hassle, i just decided to make second EFI partition on my second disk dedicated for my Arch installation.